# JavaScript seemingly unable to access object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have this object, Looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to access the `when_is_meeting` property.  I dont have any issue accessing any other property in this object. But if I try to access `when_is_meeting` I get an `undefined` as seen above next to "WHEN IS IT"

This is what the code looks like....

```
var listOfObjects = [];
    for (var modelData in responseData) {
        listOfObjects.push(service.create(name, responseData[modelData]));
        console.log('RESP', response.data.content[modelData]);
        console.log('WHEN IS IT!!!',response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting);
    }
```

Does anyone know what the heck is going on here? Did I spell something wrong? I've been over it 50 times. Must be something simple im overlooking.

----------------EDIT------HERE IS THE WHOLE SERVICE----------------------

```
    service.fetch = function (name, id, options) {
    options = options || {};
    const ModelClass = service.models[name];
    const baseUrl = ModelClass.getUrl(service.getBaseUrl(ModelClass), ModelClass.getModelName());
    let url;
    let paged = false;
    let pageList = false;


    if (id) {
        if (id instanceof models.BaseModel) {
            const BaseModelModelName = id.getModelName();
            let baseModelWithId = ModelClass.getUrl(service.getBaseUrl(), BaseModelModelName);
            url = [baseModelWithId, id.getId(), ModelClass.getModelName(), ''].join('/');
            pageList = true;
        } else {
            url = [baseUrl, id].join('/');
        }
    } else {
        pageList = true;
        url = [baseUrl, ''].join('/');
    }

    if (options.path) {
        url = url + options.path;
        delete options.path;
    }

    if (typeof options.paged === 'object') {
        let currentPage = options.paged.page;
        let pageSize = options.paged.page_size || 20;
        paged = options.paged;
        options.page = currentPage;
        options.size = pageSize;

        if (options.paged.sort) {
            let sortParam = options.paged.sort;

            options.sort = sortParam.param+','+sortParam.order;
        }

        delete options.paged;
    }

    return AuthRequestsService.load.then(function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': AuthRequestsService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
            },
            params: options,
            json: true
        });
    }).then(function (response) {
            console.log('RESPONSE',response);
            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.content.length; i++){

              if (response.data.content[i].activity_history_type == 3){

                let builder = JSON.parse(response.data.content[i].relations);
                let secondaryUrl = AppSettings.apiUrl + ['/advisor/meetings', builder.meeting].join('/');

                $http({
                    url: secondaryUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': AuthRequestsService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
                    },
                    method:'GET',
                    json:true,

                }).then(function(res){
                   response.data.content[i].when_is_meeting = res.data.meeting_date;
                   console.log('WHEN IS',response.data.content[i].when_is_meeting); // <-- this works
                })
              }
            }
            if (!pageList) {
                return service.create(name, response.data);
            } else {
                let responseData = response.data;
                if (paged) {
                    responseData = response.data.content;
                }

                var listOfObjects = [];
                for (var modelData in responseData) {
                    listOfObjects.push(service.create(name, responseData[modelData]));
                    console.log('RESP', response.data.content[modelData]);
                    listOfObjects[modelData].when_is_meeting = response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting;
                    listOfObjects[modelData].whatever = 44;
                    console.log('response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting',response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting);
                    console.log('listOfObjects[modelData].when_is_meeting', listOfObjects[modelData].when_is_meeting);
                    console.log('listOfObjects[modelData].whatever', listOfObjects[modelData].whatever);
                    console.log('Keys', Object.keys(response.data.content[modelData]));

                    // console.log('PRE IF', response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting);
                    // listOfObjects[modelData].when_is_meeting = response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting;
                    // console.log('IFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF', listOfObjects[modelData].when_is_meeting);
                    // console.log('IN FOR LOOP RESP', response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting);
                    // console.log('listOfObjects[modelData] PART 2', listOfObjects[modelData]);
                    function testForKey() {
                        if (typeof response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting !== "undefined") {
                            // when_is_meeting now exists! Do stuff with it here.
                            console.log("We now have the key:", response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting)
                        }
                        else {
                            // when_is_meeting is still missing. Try again in 200ms.
                            window.setTimeout(testForKey, 200);
                            console.log('TTTIIMMMEEEEOOOUUUTTT');
                        }
                    }
                    testForKey();
                }


                if (paged) {
                  console.log('#########################', listOfObjects);
                    return {
                        objects: listOfObjects,
                        totalPages: response.data.totalPages,
                        currentPage: response.data.number,
                        isMore: (!response.data.last),
                        totalElements: response.data.totalElements
                    };
                } else {
                    return listOfObjects;
                }
            }
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: could there be some hidden chars in the key?

Comment: Can you by any chance produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If not, how is the the object created (literal, JSON.parse, Object.create, etc)? How is the property defined (direct assignment, defineProperty, class instantiation, array accessor, etc) and how is it set (defineProperty, assignment, etc)? Which environments does it occur (Chrome, Firefox, Node.js, etc),

Comment: What happens if you use another property? Just for the hell of it, try `[]` notation.

Comment: What's your response, when you log with `Object.keys`? `console.log('Keys', Object.keys(response.data.content[modelData]))`

Comment: When you expand the toggle to view an object, the console shows what it has *now*, not what it had at the point in time the log statement was executed. So probably something is adding `when_is_meeting` after your log statement are run. This is very common in Ajax scenarios and indeed your code looks like you are handling an Ajax response, so this could be the problem. Can we see more code? Ref - http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

Comment: @Steven the key I am looking for (when_is_meeting) is not in the list...oddly enough

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think so, I defined the key.  Is there some way to check?

Comment: @PM77-1 I added a '''listOfObjects[modelData].whatever = 44''' right before i add the timestamp, and I logged it, and.....i can grab the key data... now im more confused then ever.

Comment: @sifriday I am handling an ajax response.  I didn't know that was a scenario that could occur.

Comment: yep, and the debug you ran on @Steven's suggestion confirms it. Can we see more of your code? Or, you could write a crude handler to just wait for the key you need to become available. I'll describe this in an answer, I think we are on the right lines.

Comment: Also, having just written that example, I noticed an odd inconsistency between `response.data` and `responseData` ... is it possible you should be looking for `when_is_meeting` in the latter?

Comment: try: `console.log('RESP', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data.content[modelData])));`, which will output a copy of the Object as it existed at the time the `console.log()` executed. Note that using JSON in this manner has some drawbacks, as converting to and from JSON is neither always possible (it can throw an error), nor does it always produce exactly the same contents for the Object converted. As long as you are aware of the exact extent of those limitations, this can be an effective way to find out the state of an Object at a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs because when you expand the toggle to view an object the console show what it has *now*, not what it had at the time it was logged.

This is explained well here: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

This scenario is not uncommon when you are working with Ajax. You are trying to access the result before everything has completed; ie, something else in your code is working on your `response.data` and adding in the missing key after your `console.log` statements.

This is confirmed by the logging statement suggested in the comments above by @Steven.  `Object.keys(response.data.content[modelData]))` will show the keys available at the time the log statement is made and hence does not have the same problem as just logging the object itself to the console. The results from that confirm `when_is_meeting` is indeed missing at log-time.

To fix this properly, we need to see more of your code so we can work out why you are trying to access your result before other things finish using it.

Or you can do a crude workaround using timeouts to test the `response.data.content[modelData]` for the availability of `when_is_meeting` and only access it when it exists, like the example below. But this is not really recommended - much better to figure out where the problem lies in your response handling.

```
var listOfObjects = [];
for (var modelData in responseData) {
    listOfObjects.push(service.create(name, responseData[modelData]));

    // testForKey looks for the required key 'when_is_meeting' and if it does not
    // exist it starts a timeout to test for it again in the future.
    function testForKey() {
        if (typeof response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting !== "undefined") {
            // when_is_meeting now exists! Do stuff with it here.
            console.log("We now have the key:", response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting)
        }
        else {
            // when_is_meeting is still missing. Try again in 200ms.
            window.setTimeout(testForKey, 200);
        }
    }
    testForKey();
}
```

(I've not tested this code - it might have syntax errors)

### Update - a fix for your supplied code

Your supplied code shows that as predicted the `when_is_meeting` key is being added to your result in a separate Ajax call. This call complete asynchronously and as such its result is not available to your log statements below it. This fragment shows one approach for fixing it. As before, I have not syntax-checked this code.

```
return AuthRequestsService.load.then(function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': AuthRequestsService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
        },
        params: options,
        json: true
    });
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('RESPONSE',response);
    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.content.length; i++){

      if (response.data.content[i].activity_history_type == 3){

        let builder = JSON.parse(response.data.content[i].relations);
        let secondaryUrl = AppSettings.apiUrl + ['/advisor/meetings', builder.meeting].join('/');

        // Store the result of this $http call as a promise.
        response.data.content[i].when_is_meeting_promise = $http({
            url: secondaryUrl,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': AuthRequestsService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
            },
            method:'GET',
            json:true,

        })
        // Remove your .then handler from here. It will be dealt with below.
        //.then(function(res){
        //   response.data.content[i].when_is_meeting = res.data.meeting_date;
        //   console.log('WHEN IS',response.data.content[i].when_is_meeting); // <-- this works
        //})
      }
    }
    if (!pageList) {
        return service.create(name, response.data);
    } else {
        let responseData = response.data;
        if (paged) {
            responseData = response.data.content;
        }

        var listOfObjects = [];
        for (var modelData in responseData) {
            // OK, now access the promise you stored above. This means you'll be sure you'll
            // have the when_is_meeting key.
            responseData[modelData].when_is_meeting_promise.then(function(when_is_meeting_result) {
                // Now you can copy the neeting date into your responseData object.
                responseData[modelData].when_is_meeting = when_is_meeting_result.data.meeting_date;

                // Carry on....
                listOfObjects.push(service.create(name, responseData[modelData]));
                console.log('RESP', response.data.content[modelData]);

                // This should now work...
                console.log('response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting',response.data.content[modelData].when_is_meeting);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There were no syntax errors, but the else statement fires indefinately, which is even more odd....

Comment: I added the whole service to my original example, under the EDIT line... Thanks @sifriday

Comment: Thanks. I can see the problem. Sure enough you're loading `when_is_meeting` in a separate Ajax call. That won't have finished when your code below tries to access it. I'll add a suggestion for fixing it to my answer.

Comment: Oh, and the setTimeout hack won't work inside a loop - each time it runs the value of `response.data.content[modelData]` will have changed.